pyodbc w/ iSeries Access ODBC Driver: TABLE in DATABASE not valid for operation. (-7008) (SQLExecDirectW)')
i have a problem with pyodbc, commiting an update statement in python to a as400/db2 - this is my code:
class CDP_ODBC():
    def __init__(self):
       self.cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
            'DRIVER={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};'
            'SYSTEM=192.XXX.XXX.XXX;'
            'UID=UID;'
        'PWD=PWD;')
        
       self.cursor = self.cnxn.cursor()


    def update(self):
        sqlstr = f"""
            UPDATE TABLE.DATABASE
            SET TESTMODELL = 1
            WHERE TESTID= 1
        """

        self.cursor.execute(sqlstr)
        self.cnxn.commit()

I get this error:
(<class 'pyodbc.Error'>, Error('HY000', '[HY000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL7008 - TABLE in DATABASE not valid for operation. (-7008) (SQLExecDirectW)'), <traceback object at 0x0C947A88>)

I have already tried to include 'TXNISOLATION=0;' and set self.cnxn.autocommit=False but still same error.
Do you have an idea?

The "not valid for operation" likely means the table you're trying to update is not journaled, and thus not subject to commitment control. You actually want to set autocommit to True, or include the WITH NC clause in your SQL statement. Either way, don't use self.cnxn.commit().
